# Books on advanced desserts?

Tags: dessert

So I got hooked onto "advanced" (dunno how to call it correctly) dessert making and that primary comes from two books that I accidentally got hold of:

"Daren Purchese - Sweet studio"

"Cheryl Wakerhauser - Modern French Pastry".

Now I would like to dig deeper into this subject. Since I'm not an English native speaker, How can I find similar books that are more advanced than a regular dessert cookbook (e.g. they require use of molds, use spray guns, etc.). Maybe this field has a specific name?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Amazon's "Customers who bought this item also bought" section when looking at those 2 books.

The book "Elements of Desserts" from Francisco J. Migoya looks nice.

Also try to find El Bulli books, even if they are not dessert exclusive, you will find amazing (hard to reproduce) desserts.